# How to make jqGrid row a link to an Action in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, hyperlink, jqgrid-asp.net

I finally got my asp.net grid to display data...
But I need it to link to an action when clicking on one of the rows... or if need be, a single column How can I get a route into one of my columns or rows in MVC3?

I am using jqGrid btw...

Here is how I set up my Grid

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
                        shrinkToFit: false,
                        autowidth: true,
                        datatype: 'jsonstring',
                        mtype: 'POST',
                        colNames: [
                                   'MRN',
                                   'Hospital Fin',
                                   'First Name',
                                   'Last Name',
                                   'Date of birth',
                                   'Completed Pathway',
                                   'Completed Pathway Reason',
                                   'PCP Appointment',
                                   'Specialist Appointment',
                                   'Admit Date'
                                   ],
                        colModel: [
                                   { name: 'MRN', width: 125, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'Hospital_Fin', width: 145, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'First_Name', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'Last_Name', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'Date_of_birth', width: 145, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'Completed_Pathway', width: 125, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'Completed_Pathway_Reason', width: 165, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'PCP_Appointment', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'Specialist_Appointment', width: 125, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'Admit_Date', width: 185, align: 'left' }],
                        rowNum: 10,
                        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                        sortname: 'Id',
                        sortorder: "desc",
                        viewrecords: true,
                        imgpath: '/Content/themes/UPMC-theme/images',
                        caption: 'My first grid'
    });
```

Any way to make an entire row clickable to an action method?
To open my view I need to call a controller and an action...

EditEncoutner is the controller, and EditEncounter is the Action...

```
public ActionResult EditEncounter(int encounterId, int popId)
        {
            string UID = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            DataRepository dr = new DataRepository();
            PatientACOModel patMod = dr.Get(encounterId, UID);
            TempData["POPULATIONID"] = popId;
            return View(patMod);
        }
```

Now I write up the JSON string myself... I am think of putting an `<a />` tag in the relevant columns.  But that would mean I am not making the entire row clickable, and I would then have to chose which column to put the link... 
I could just make an edit column, which is what I will do if all else fails, I was kind of hoping for a more elegant solution however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your View is binded to a `List` of `Products` class objects

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>
<table>
@foreach(var product in Model)
{
 <tr class="trClickable" data-viewurl="@Url.Action("View","Product",new {@id=product.ID})">
   <td>
     @product.Name
   </td>
   <td>
     @product.Price
   </td>
 </tr>
}
</table>
```

We will add a little javascript to capture the `click` event of the `row`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
     $(".trClickable").click(function () {
         var item = $(this);
         window.location.href = item.data("viewurl");
     });
 });
```

Assuming you have an action method called `View` inside your `ProductController` which accepts a parameter called `id` and show some data in it's view